# Django Query Does not exist

Tags: django

I'm been trying to create an app that allows users to follow each other profile since yesterday and today and I haven't been successful so far.

I'm having trouble creating a following function that allows me to retrieve users from a particular user he follows.

Example . If John follows Diana . I want to able to retrieve the user called Diana and use it with my modules.

I'm really sorry if this doesn't make sense . I'm trying my hardest to explain my situation.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Most of these solutions gave me no query

***This was one of the solutions I tried.***

```
class UserLink(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = "following_set")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = "follower_set")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s is following %s" % (self.from_user.username,self.to_user.username)
    def save(self,**kwargs):
        if self.from_user == self.to_user:
            raise ValueError("Cannot follow yourself ")
        super(UserLink , self).save(**kwargs)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('to_user','from_user'),)
```

I tried to retrieve the users that a particular user followed and use it against my modules such as Person but it gave me an error No query exist.

```
def Follow(request,username=""):
        if request.method == "POST":
                username = request.POST.get('follow',False)
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                UserLink.objects.create(from_user=request.user,to_user=user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Profile'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Profile'))
```

***I also tried this following function but it only followed himself and I changed self to User but it didn't allow me to put the person to follow***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)

>>>from pet.models import *
>>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>>user = User.objects.get(username='Peter')
>>>user1 = User.objects.get(username='Sarah')
>>>p = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user,follows=user1)
>>>Error no field called follows
```

How can I create a following class that allows retrieve the people that they followed and use it with my modules such as Person?

Can someone help me . Thannk you community!

Comment: @catherine I don't know how to explain properly but I'll try . im trying to create a class and the purpose of that class is when a user following another user . I can retrieve and display the boards the user he followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, youu are on the right track with the many to many relationship.  What you need is to modify your existing Person class to include this information.

Since information about who someone follows or is following is essentially information about that person and so you shouldn't really need to define a new class to implement that functionality.

I would suggest modifying your Person like so.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

What this line does is makes a many to many relationship between the class Person and its self.

Many to many relationships work a little different to other relationships and I suggest you read the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/.

But you should now be able to setup and access the relationship like this.

```
>>>john = Person.objects.get(name="John")
>>>diana = Person.objects.get(name="Diana")
>>>john.following.add(diana)//setup the many to many relationship
>>>john.save()

>>>john.following.all()
//This should return a queryset of Person objects which john is following.
//eg Diana

>>>diana.followers.all()
//This should return a queryset of Person objects which are following Diana.
//eg. John.
```

Easy, how awesome is Django!

Comment: Okay , for example If john is following diana and Peter . How can I display diana and peter names?and how do I get it to relate with other modules like diana's board?

Comment: I learn't from you how to query for all people that a user is following . In a scenario . I want to display all the boards from the user that John is following how could I do that? following is not assoicated with User

Comment: Its a bit hard to explain in a comment, it may be worth asking another question (or two since your two comments are asking different things).  The first one, you would need to get the User object and then work in reverse to get too Board.

Keep in mind many to many relationships return a queryset. Not the objects themselves. This might be your problem.

Comment: Oh okay . That is actually my problem . I'm going to do some research before I ask a question . I thank you very much Ze'ev G and I hope to see you next time :]

Comment: You solved this question at the very best and I couldn't thank you enough :]